# Graphs with zero spectrum / nilpotent symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Is there a graph theoretic characterization of those graphs with zero spectrum?

Alternatively, can one at least characterize all symmetric nilpotent (complex) matrices, so that one could recognize those graphs by their adjacency matrices?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Assuming simple, undirected graphs) The $k$-th spectral moment is defined as $s_k=\lambda_1^k+...+\lambda_n^k$, where $\{\lambda_i\}$ are the eigenvalues. The $k$-th moment has an interpretation: it is the number of closed paths of length $k$ (these paths can be self-intersecting). If all eigenvalues are 0, ...

Comment: If I understand you right, graphs with zero spectrum consists of no edges, because every edge would lead to a closed path of length 2. Right?

Comment: @Dune: right. You can prove that nice little fact (about the $k$-th spectrum) by induction.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: If the eigenvalues are zero then the adjacency matrix is similar to the zero matrix, therefore it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that that the trace of $A^2$ is just the number of non zero entries of A, but this trace is zero.

Comment: I see, that the trace of $A^2$ equals the double number of edges. But how do you deduce, that it is zero?